# are some characters automatically escaped?

Tags: php

I'm inputting some fields into a database. One had a value of

```
foto's
```

and when I checked in the `$_POST[]` where that was contained it had

```
foto\'s
```

does this happen automatically? I have (not yet) any escaping in my script.

Update: So it's the magic quotes that is doing it. The php.ini-file looked like this:

```
; Magic quotes
;
```

So I changed it to:

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

But in phpinfo this is  still on:

```
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
```

Comment: Yes, right now the `mysql_query()` or `mysqli_query()` will be escaping. :)

Comment: probably `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) in action. Disable them *immediately* and then follow the usual best practices to properly escape user-supplied input depending on what you are going to do with it.

Comment: @Veltar: Did you restart the web server?

Answer (score 0):

Trun **magic quotes** off.

[Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) to see how to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Always turn off magic code as has portability issue.

Below php code will be useful for you and this code will work even if the magic quote is on ( below php version 6):

```
function escape($string) {
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '6', '<')) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $string = stripcslashes($string);
    }
    if (!is_numeric($string))
        $string = addslashes($string);
    return $string;
}
```

Usage:

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee(id, name) VALUES(1001, '".escape($_POST['name'])."')";

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1 because this is simply horrible: `addslashes` cannot protect you from SQL injection across the board. There are lots of answers on SO that explain how to do this correctly (and in every case they need to do something database-specific).